# Maximum Likelihood Estimator for a given density function

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

I have the following problem: Assume you observe $Y_1,...,Y_N$ independently from the distribution $f_y$:

$$
 f_{Y}(y)=\frac{12}{12-\theta}\left\{\begin{array}{ll}-\theta(y-0.5)^{2}+1 & \text { if } \quad 0<y<1 \\ 0 & \text { o } / \mathrm{w}\end{array}\right. 
$$

Compute the maximum likelihood estimator $\hat{\theta}$.

The $+1$ term is preventing me to solve easily this problem. First we can compute the likelihood function:

$$L(\theta)=\prod^n_{i=1}f_{Y_i}(y_i)=\left(\frac{12}{12-\theta}\right)^n\prod^n_{i=1}(-\theta(y_i-0.5)^2+1)$$
Then the log likelihood:
$$l(\theta)=n\log(12)-n\log(12-\theta)+\sum^n_{i=1}\log(-\theta(y_i-0.5)^2+1)$$
Computing the derivative we obtain:

$$l'(\theta)=\frac{n}{12-\theta}+\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{(y_i-0.5)^2}{\theta(y_i-0.5)^2-1}$$

If I try to solve $l'(\theta)=0$, it is really impossible to find the correct theta because of the $+1$ term. Any idea how I could solve this?

Comment: This does not prevent the existence of an MLE nor its derivation by numerical methods.

Comment: Note that the expression of the log derivative is formally identical to the logistic regression likelihood equation.

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you for your answer. I have the logistic regression likelihood equation in front of me but I struggle to see any ressemblance with the derivative $l'(\theta)$

Comment: Is this a homework question? This would be tough stuff, because there does not seem to be an analytical solution. Or does the assignment asko for a solution in terms of an R function?

Comment: Do you not have some restrictions on $y$ that depend on $\theta$?  For instance, $0<y<1$ when $0<\theta\leq 4$ but when $\theta>4$ you'll need to have $\frac{\sqrt{\theta }-2}{2 \sqrt{\theta }}<y<\frac{\sqrt{\theta }+2}{2 \sqrt{\theta }}$ to have a positive density and modify the constant of integration so that the density integrates to 1?